# Vagrant and Homestead

Tags: laravel, vagrant, laravel-5, homestead

What I'm wanting to accomplish is installing Vagrant and Laravel's Homestead on my local computer so that I can do away with MAMP which I actually deleted yesterday.

I had installed both Vagrant and Homestead however I later found out that my computer wouldn't let me run the `php artisan migrate` command because it was saying no file found.

I did some digging and had someone tell me to do some changes in the my.cnf file.

So I logged into my VM and tried to locate the file however it informed me there was no file with that name or extension inside the MySQL folder.

Can someone help me get settled back up so I can continue normally on my project?

```
Me-iMac:~ me$ vagrant box remove laravel/homestead
Box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.2.5) with provider 'virtualbox' appears
to still be in use by at least one Vagrant environment. Removing
the box could corrupt the environment. We recommend destroying
these environments first:

default (ID: e5a3663ef2cf4e91a02e8c7e99fa584b)

Are you sure you want to remove this box? [y/N] y
Removing box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.2.5) with provider 'virtualbox'...
me-iMac:~ me$ vagrant box add laravel/homestead
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    box: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead
This box can work with multiple providers! The providers that it
can work with are listed below. Please review the list and choose
the provider you will be working with.

1) virtualbox
2) vmware_desktop

Enter your choice: 1
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.2.5) for provider: virtualbox
    box: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.2.5/providers/virtualbox.box
==> box: Successfully added box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.2.5) for 'virtualbox'!
me-iMac:~ me$ homestead ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.10 (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-23-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Last login: Mon Apr 20 14:06:45 2015 from 10.0.2.2
vagrant@homestead:~$ locate my.cnf
vagrant@homestead:~$ which mysql
/usr/bin/mysql
vagrant@homestead:~$
```

Comment: my.cnf is almost definitely not where your problem is. Make sure you're running the `php artisan` commands from within the homestead VM and within the laravel project root directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your Terminal dump, I can't tell whether you've created your Homestead.yaml file. Make sure you do that so that you can access your development files from within Homestead. Run `homestead init`, then `homestead edit`, and configure your shared folders and Nginx sites. Once done, you'll need to `homestead destroy` and `homestead up` again to allow the changes to take effect.

After all that, SSH back into Homestead, change to the shared folder you set up, and try to run `php artisan migrate`, making sure that there is in fact an `artisan` file in the Laravel installation directory.